# How to format data passed to stored procedure to be used with IN clause?

Tags: c#, sql-server

For example, let's say I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_Members]
    @IsActive INT,
    @Gender VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    SELECT
        first_name, last_name, gender
    FROM 
        members
    WHERE 
        is_active IN (@IsActive)
        AND gender IN (@Gender)
GO
```

And I have the following c# code to call this stored procedure:

```
ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();

lst.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsActive", IsActive));
lst.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gender", Gender));

try
{
    return this.ExecuteDataTable("get_Members", lst);
}
```

In my table, `is_active` would be an `int` type with accepted values of `1` and `0`.

Gender is a `varchar` column with accepted values of `Male`, `Female`, `Unknown`.

What kind of variables would I need to use to pass in values of `1, 0` for the `IsActive` SQL parameter and `Male`, `Female`, `Unknown` for the `Gender` parameter so that it will work properly in the `IN` clause?

I'm a visual learner so a visual example would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: A table-valued parameter would be best. See http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Dispensing with IsActive, because that is simple to explain:

Declare your parameter as `DbType.Boolean`, set its `.Value` to a c# bool, and the `BIT 0/1` column on the server side will be mapped properly as `0=false`, `1=true`

#### Moving onto your IN query:

You can't pass values to an IN like that. If you want to pass gender as a VARCHAR you'll have to do something like:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[get_Members]
    @IsActive int
    ,@Gender varchar(max)

AS

SELECT
    first_name
    ,last_name
    ,gender
FROM members
WHERE is_active IN (@IsActive)
AND @Genders LIKE CONCAT('%.', gender, '.%')

GO
```

---

```
ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();

lst.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsActive", SqlDbType.Boolean) { Value = IsActive });

Gender = ".";
if(isMale)
  Gender += "male.";
if(isFemale)
  Gender += "female.";
if(isUnknown)
  Gender += "unknown.";

lst.Add(new SqlParameter("@Genders", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = Gender });

try
{
    return this.ExecuteDataTable("get_Members", lst);
}
```

The important thing to note is that your C#, wanting `female`s and `unknown`s, shall build a string that looks like:

```
.female.unknown.
```

And the sql becomes:

```
'.female.unknown.' LIKE '%.<gender from column>.%'
```

So youre not doing "column like value", you're doing "values like %column%"

```
--hence when the column is male
'.female.unknown.' LIKE '%.male.%' --FALSE

--hence when the column is female
'.female.unknown.' LIKE '%.female.%' --TRUE

--hence when the column is unknown
'.female.unknown.' LIKE '%.unknown.%' --TRUE
```

---

Why can't you do it like you had?

Because this doesn't work:

```
WHERE Gender IN ('female, male')
```

This works:

```
WHERE Gender IN ('female', 'male')
```

These two things are very different

If you're desperate to use IN, you'll have to have more variables:

```
WHERE Gender IN (@g1, @g2, @g3)
```

And your c# can set `@g1 = 'male'`, `@g2 = 'female'`, `@g3 = 'nonexistent_or_null_or_even_male_again'` if you want just the males and females

#### Which would I use?

Probably this latter form, as **there is a good chance that an index on Gender wouldn't be used** if you're trying to shoehorn things into one varchar by using the "values like %column%" approach.

Final note; there's nothing stopping you using a single varchar parameters and cutting it up in the procedure. Most simple would be to use sqlserver 2016+ and the STRING_SPLIT function:

```
WHERE Gender IN (
  SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Genders, '.') WHERE LEN(LTRIM(value)) > 0
)
```

But you can get more involved in cutting things up with SUBSTRING etc if you want. I didn't immediately go to this option because it's quite DB specific whether strings can be split easily, server side, without user defined functions etc (and I didn't want to get into writing one that was universally applicable on all sql servers, using left/right/substring etc)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are going to only be parsing 3 values, a different method might be to split your data with [`PARSENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Note that `PARSENAME` won't help if you have more than 4 items in a delimited string or if any of your items have more than 128 characters. The documentation (at the time of writing) is wrong, as the actual return type is `sysname`, which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128)`.

```
DECLARE @Gender varchar(20) = 'male,female'; 
/*
@Gender does not need to be a varchar(MAX). 'female,unknown,male' is 19 characters.
You are never going to be passing 2,147,483,648 to define 3 genders.
*/
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       gender
FROM members
WHERE is_active = @IsActive --Considering @IsActive is an int, this will only have one value
AND gender IN (SELECT V.Gender
               FROM (VALUES(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Gender,',','.'),1)),
                           (PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Gender,',','.'),2)),
                           (PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Gender,',','.'),3))) V(Gender)
               WHERE V.Gender IS NOT NULL);
```

Using the `CONCAT` method, like in the other answer, will make your query non-SARGable; which could have big performance issues.

Comment: Neat trick, though PARSENAME's a wee bit hacky.. It was intended for pulling apart references to tables etc, like 'dbo.Northwind.orders' and I'd only use it in a really narrow context such as this; many things could break it, in many different ways. Future visitors to this question take note to educate yourselves fully of the practical limitations of using PARSENAME

Comment: @CaiusJard for when you only have a maximum of 4 items, `PARSENAME` is pretty useful, but after that then you really need a "proper" spitter; such as `STRING_SPLIT` or `delimitedsplit8k_lead`. I'll add a note to note to clarify this, however, as perhaps I was not clear enough.